# Grails explicit transaction

Tags: grails, transactions

I have a Grails Service with a method processing multiple files.
Each file will be processed (inserting n-domains) and if correct it will be moved in a folder "backup", if something goes wrong (validations or domain saving) it will be moved in a folder "errors"
I need to commit database changes on file correct and rollback if file is wrong (not loosing previous files processed on database)

now I have @Transactional on service class, but it commits or rollback all data

```
@Transactional
class DocumentoTrasportoService extends GenericService {

  public void processFiles(String path){
     def pathFile = new File(path)
     pathFile.eachFile{
        try {
            processFile(it)
            //I want to commit here
            //move file to folder "backup"
        } catch (Exception ex){
            //I want to rollback here
            //move file to folder "errors"
        }
     }
  }

  public void processFile(File file){
     //read file
     //do validations
     //insert domains
  }

}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need more programatic and fine grained control of your transactions within that service I would recommend you look at using [withTransaction](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html) instead. This way you can execute each file within it's own transaction instead of a single transaction as a service method.

In theory your code would look something like this:

```
class DocumentoTrasportoService extends GenericService {

  public void processFiles(String path){
     def pathFile = new File(path)
     pathFile.eachFile{
        MyDomainClass.withTransaction { status ->
          try {
              processFile(it)
              //move file to folder "backup"
          } catch (Exception ex){
              //I want to rollback here
              status.setRollbackOnly()
              //move file to folder "errors"
          }
       } // end of transaction
     }
  }

  public void processFile(File file){
     //read file
     //do validations
     //insert domains
  }
```

Notice that you only need to set the status for rolling back the transaction. Hope this helps.

Comment: even if I have to insert on more than one Domain?

Comment: Yes. Even if you insert several domains within the withTransaction closure they will all be inside the same transaction.

Comment: Maght as well set static transactional=false on the service itself as well, no sense in incurring the overhead at the top level of your service.

Comment: but if I static transactional=false and a file process fails after inserting some data... this data will remain

Comment: I assume you are talking about a failure in moving the file into "backup". Since that's inside the withTransaction closure any exception there will cause the transaction to rollback because of the catch and setting setRollbackOnly(). So the only data effected will be the data inserted/updated for that file. Not other files or all files.

Comment: yes it works but only adding
    static transactional = false
at class level